# Convert #text from getNodeName to string

Tags: java, xml, text, nodename

I am parsing a XML file as follows:

```
<ROW>
<INDUSTRY_ID>1</INDUSTRY_ID>
<ID>314</ID>
</ROW>
```

Here's my code:

```
NodeList titleList = list.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
Log.w("nodeName is ",titleList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeName());
Log.w("nodeValue is ",titleList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeName());
```

I can successfully obtain the content of the  tag and  tag, namely, I got "1" and "314" resp.; However, I got #text from getNodeName().
I have also tried:

```
titleList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeName().toString()
```

But I was still getting #text. My question is how do I get "INDUSTRY_ID" and "ID" instead?

Comment: @svick The language is Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your have navigated down to the Text node. Text nodes doesn't technically have names, just (text) values. You want this:

```
NodeList titleList = list.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
Log.w("nodeName is ",titleList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeName());
Log.w("nodeValue is ",titleList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(3).getNodeName());
```

However, this is a very non-robust way of accessing element nodes and values, since it depends on white space formatting. Use Xpath to retrieve a list of needed elements and access their respective names and values

```
XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance();
NodeList elements = (NodeList) xp.evaluate(doc, "//ROW/*", XPathConstants.NODESET); 
for(int i=0; i < elements.getLength(); ++i) {
    String name = elements.itemt(i).getNodeName();
    String value = elements.itemt(i).getTextContent();
}
```